# AngularJS watcher changes the value of my function back to its original

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**So this is my pseudo code :**

```
var anotherFunction = function () { //do stuff 1 }

scope.$watch("myFunction",function (){
   eval("scope.myFunction = anoterFunction");
}

scope.myFunction = function () { //do stuff 1 };
```

What is happening is that immediately after the eval the myFunction equals to anotherFunction, but right after the scope of that watch, the value goes back to its initial one!

Any help here? It only happens sometimes tough, its kind of random, sometimes the value gets replaces sometimes it doesnt.

Any idea why is angular behaving this way?

Comment: Why do you need to watch a **function**?

Comment: because I have two scripts executing in parallel

Comment: show your code in JSFiddele http://jsfiddle.net/, this should be a good start